# unable to fetch values from action bean to jsp using stripes

Tags: stripes

My action bean is

```
@HandlesEvent("getExcessesWidget")
public Resolution getExcessesWidget(){
    primaryCO ="situser5";
    excessList = excessManagementUiService.**getExcessesWidget**(primaryCO);
    return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/excessManagement/inbox.jsp");
}
```

GetExcessesWidget method --

```
public FilteredUIExcessList getExcessesWidget(String primaryCO){
    if(primaryCO != null && !primaryCO.trim().equals("")){
        List<CrExcessMaster> crExcessMasterList =       getExcessDbService().getExcessesWidget(primaryCO);
        return UIBeanFormatter.formatWidgetBean(crExcessMasterList);
    }
    return null;
}
```

My UIBeanFormatter.formatWidgetBean method is

```
public static FilteredUIExcessList formatWidgetBean(List<CrExcessMaster> crExcessMasterList){
        if(crExcessMasterList != null){

            FilteredUIExcessList filteredUIExcessList = new FilteredUIExcessList();

            List<CustomerExcessUIBean> widgetList = new ArrayList<CustomerExcessUIBean>();

            for(CrExcessMaster crExcessMaster : crExcessMasterList){

                ExcessUIBean excessUIBean = new ExcessUIBean();
                excessUIBean.setExcessId(crExcessMaster.getExcessId().toString());              
                excessUIBean.setOpenDate(sdf.format(crExcessMaster.getOpenDate()));
                excessUIBean.setExcessAmount(crExcessMaster.getMaxExcessAmount().toString());
                excessUIBean.setDaValueForUser(Integer.parseInt(excessDbService.getDaLevelForUser("situser5")));

                CustomerExcessUIBean customerExcessUIBean = new CustomerExcessUIBean();
                customerExcessUIBean.setClientName(getClientName(crExcessMaster.getCif()));
                customerExcessUIBean.setUltimateParent(getParentEntity(crExcessMaster.getCif()));   

if (widgetList.contains(customerExcessUIBean)){
                    widgetList.get(widgetList.indexOf(customerExcessUIBean)).getExcessList().add(excessUIBean);
                }
                else{
                    customerExcessUIBean.getExcessList().add(excessUIBean);
                    widgetList.add(customerExcessUIBean);
                }
            }
            filteredUIExcessList.setWidgetList(widgetList);
            return filteredUIExcessList;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My values display correctly in action bean class but i am unable to fetch it in jsp file
My jsp is

```
<s:form method="POST" action="/excessList.htm?getExcessesWidget=true"
        id="form">
        <table border="2px" bordercolor="black" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>Excesses to be actioned
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Excess ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>DA</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${actionBean.excessList}" var="excess">
                        <c:forEach items="${excess.widgetList}"     var="customerExcess">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${customerExcess.excessId }"></c:out></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${customerExcess.openDate }"></c:out></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${customerExcess.excessAmount }"></c:out></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${customerExcess.daValueForUser }"></c:out></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:forEach> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </s:form>
```

Unable to find my mistake....any help is most appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: anybody dere to help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where excessList is defined, make sure it has public getter.